# Did the Tree of Life in the Garden of Eden have sapphire?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, trees, gan-eden, gemstone

I heard one teaching that Moshe's staff was sapphire, and another that it was the Tree of Life. Is there any connection between the two, like maybe the fruits on the Tree of Life were like sapphires or something like that, or any connections made in the commentaries?